# Circular Array Modifier places subject too far

Tags: modifiers

I've been following few tutorials on how to use the `Array Modifier` to duplicate objects around something. I'm going mad as for some reason it places the arrayed objects ridiculously far from each other, I can't even see them but its dimension is X:38515587km ... As shown below.

The way I did it:

1. created a circle
2. placed its origin to somewhere away
3. set the 3D cursor to the origin of the previously created circle
4. created an empty
5. added an array modifier to the circle
6. set object offset and other stuff according to the screenshot

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: According to the screenshot you didn't include one sttep which is scaling object. Try applying scale for the object which is arrayed.

Comment: It's doing some random stuff, not sure how to do that. The circles are out of control, their size and location is out of control ;(

Comment: YEAH I've found out! I was scaling the circles in object mode, doing it in edit mode fixed the issue!!!!

Comment: @MrZak Now I see what you mean. Thanks, thats much simpler fix.